# Problems with finding unique values in regEx

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have a javascript regEx that is supposed to find all values with curly brackets around them eg {} and return a list of the unique values. I thought that it was working perfectly but I found that it doesn't work depending on the sequence of values.

For example: If the target document contains {lorem}{lorem}{ipsem}{ipsem} the script logs what's wanted [lorem, ipsem] but {lorem}{ipsem}{ipsem}{lorem} the script logs [lorem, ipsem,lorem]. What am I doing wrong!?

```js
function getVariables() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var str = doc.getText(); //get the text of the document
  var result = str.match(/{.*?}/g).map(function(val) {
    return val.replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, "");
    //return val.replace(/(^.*\[|\].*$)/g,'');
  });

  //The purpose of sort_unique is to find one of every value or string represented in an array
  function sort_unique(arr) {
    if (result.length === 0) return arr;
    arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a * 1 - b * 1;
    });
    var ret = [arr[0]];
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i - 1] !== arr[i]) {
        ret.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }

    for (var index = 0; index < ret.length; index++) {
      Logger.log(ret[index]);
    }

    return ret;
  }
  result = sort_unique(result);

  Logger.log("Getting final result for front end....");
  Logger.log(result);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe part of your problem is the sort method. If you replace

```
arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a * 1 - b * 1;
});
```

with

```
arr = arr.sort();
```

Then the function appears to work, at least on my side.

This will run in O(n log n) time. You can do better without sorting, if you store the values you've found so far in a map instead of an array. This would run in linear time.

(Also you'll want to replace `if (result.length === 0) return arr;` with `if (arr.length === 0) return arr;` just to make your `sort_unique` function completely independent of the surrounding function.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).  Store each of the regex matches in a set, then return `Array.from(mySet)`.

```js
var mySet = new Set();
str.match(/{.*?}/g).forEach(function(val) {
  mySet.add(val.replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, ""));
});

return Array.from(mySet);
```

A set's `add()` function is `O(1)` so the total running time is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of matches in your string.  Though, realistically, the regex search will be where most of the processing time occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You check if the subsequent items are the same and those that are not subsequent land in the resulting array.

Check if the found value is in the result, and if not add the match, else, ignore.

Use the code like

```
function getVariables() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var str = doc.getText(); //get the text of the document
  var m, result=[], rx = /{([^{}]*)}/g;
  while (m=rx.exec(str)) {
    if (result.indexOf(m[1]) == -1) {
      result.push(m[1]);
    }
  }
  result.sort(); // If you really want to sort use this
  // Logger.log(result); // View the result
}
```

The `/{([^{}]*)}/g` regex matches `{`, then captures into Group 1 zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`. So, the value you need is in `m[1]`. The `if (result.indexOf(m[1]) == -1)` checks if the value is in `result`.